# What adjective describes that something is divided into sectors?

Tags: adjectives, terminology

In particular I am looking for the correct terminology in air traffic management. Airspace is usually divided into sectors, i.e., smaller pieces of airspace.

What is the corresponding adjective? Is it a *sectored* airspace or is it a *sectorized* airspace?

Comment: Segmented? "The world's navigable airspace is divided into three-dimensional _segments_, each of which is assigned to a specific class." (Wikipedia: Airspace class)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airspace_class

Comment: @CopperKettle: I found that entry, too. However, I have never heard somebody say "segment" in the context of airspace. In my opinion "sector" is the correct terminology here. Compare this article: "The Flight Information Region controlled by a Center may be further administratively subdivided into Areas comprising two to nine sectors." (Wikipedia: Area Control Center) [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_Control_Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_Control_Center)

Comment: @mplungjan: Personally, "sectioned" sounds good to me. However, in aviation there are "sectional charts" or "sectional maps", which do not refer to the kind of division into sectors that I mean.

Comment: *Sectioned* is valid, but unfortunately it makes me think of the British use of that to mean detained under section 2 or section 3 of the Mental Health Act.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sectored* is attested:

> Circularly rounded pinions may be used as driver if they are sectored large. — 1881   F. J. Britten Watch & Clockmakers' Handbk. (ed. 4)
>
> It would appear that… the Belle Isle light… is not correctly sectored. — 1902   W. D. Jones in Times 1 Dec.

However *segmented* is much more commonly found, to the point of being accepted by some dictionaries as fully an adjective, rather than just a participle used as an adjective.

While it doesn't match the word *sector* as closely, that is often the case with those nouns, adjectives and verbs we most often use as corresponding with each other. In all, I'd favour *segmented*.